# Find the probability of a left handed person

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm attempting this problem from "The Probability Tutoring Book" by Carol Ash.

> 15% of the population is left handed. If you stop people on the street, what is the probability that
>
> a)It takes at least 20 people to get a left handed person.

My attempt:

The probability of at least asking 20 people is going to be

$$P( \geq 20\ people) = 1 - P( \leq 19\ people) $$ Which is true because of the complement rule.

We now just need to find the $P( \leq 19\ people)$

$$P( \leq 19\ people) = P( 0\ people) + P( 1\ person) +P( 2\ people)+ ... +P( 19\ people)$$
$$P( \leq 19\ people) = \sum_{i=0}^{19}{(.15)*(.85)^i}$$

So putting it all together,
$$P( \geq 20\ people) = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{19}{(.15)*(.85)^i} \approx 0.039 $$

However, according to the solutions at the back of the book:

$$P( \geq 20\ people) = P(first\ 19\ people\ are\ right\ handed)$$
$$P( \geq 20\ people) = (.85)^{19} \approx .046$$

Wy don't our two answers concur? Am I missing something? Is the answer key wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"It takes $20$ people to get a left-handed person" means that the $20^{\text{th}}$ person *will be* left-handed. You are right by applying the complement: $$P( \geq 20\ \text{people}) = 1 - P( \leq 19\ \text{people})$$

However, observe carefully here that, $ P(\text{asking} \ 19 \ \text{people})$ is actually $(.15) \times (.85)^{18}$, because asking $19$ people means that the first $18$ people will be right-handed, and the $19^{\text{th}}$ *will be* left-handed.

Therefore, you just have to fix this in your formula:
$$P( \leq 19\ \text{people}) = \sum_{i=0}^{18}{(.15)*(.85)^i} $$

P.S: Notice also that we start summing from $i = 0$, which is the case where we meet a left-handed person on the first try (for which the probability is exactly $0.15$).

Summing up, the answer will be $$P( \geq 20\ \text{people}) = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{18}{(.15)*(.85)^i} \approx 0.0455 $$

Comment: OHHHH! That makes so much sense and yet is so frustrating at the same time!!

Comment: Thanks so much!!